# Intuition for gauge force as a 2-form

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, vector-fields

I understand the 2-form of a principle bundle as a measurement of the difference in horizontal lifts. In other words, if the lie bracket of two vector fields on the base does not equal to the lie bracket of the vector fields in the horizontal subspace of the tangent bundle, then the curvature is not 0. The example of a general linear group is nice, because this is just the commutator. If $X_H$ is a horizontal lift of a vector field on the base manifold, the curvature 2-form $\Omega = 0$ if and only if $$XY - YX = X_HY_H - Y_HX_H.$$ How do I understand the inability to preserve commutation under lifts as a force? Is there some local ingredient I am missing when I talk about horizontal lifts to the fiber bundle?

Comment: Please, can you define the symbols in your question? (in partcular, $\Omega$ and the subscript $H$).

Comment: Thank you for reminder. I have edited the post